# React Synthetic Events Bubble Capture with Components

Tags: reactjs, event-bubbling, dom-events, event-capturing

I am researching React Events at the moment and I have noticed an unusual issue regarding event bubble and Capture.

If I have a nested group of div tags, all with their own onClick/onClickCapture, then this works as expected. Events trigger "down/up" the DOM tree.

However, if one of them Divs is a React.Component, it will not catch the event.
I believe this is by design, where React is taking the stance that Components should always be "Stand-Alone" and therefore, should not handle events raised by other Components (even if they are nested).

Can anyone tell me if I am right in my thinking?

I have created a demo. In the demo, if you replace the Component "Top" with a standard div, it will bubble and Capture as expected.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNdBYW?editors=0010

```
const Top = (props) => (
  <div id="A" onClick={props.bubbleA} onClickCapture={props.captureA}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
)

const App = (props) => (
  <Top>A:Top Event
    <div id="B" onClick={props.bubbleB} onClickCapture={props.captureB}>B:I Propagate
      <div id="C" onClick={props.bubbleC} onClickCapture={props.captureC}>C:Don't Propagate
      </div>
    </div>
 </Top>
)

const props = {
  bubbleA: (e) => alert("bubble:A Target:" + e.target.id),
  captureA: (e) => alert("Capture:A Target:" + e.target.id),
  bubbleB: (e) => alert("bubble:B Target:" + e.target.id),
  captureB: (e) => alert("Capture:B Target:" + e.target.id),
  bubbleC: (e) => alert("bubble:C Target:" + e.target.id),
  captureC: (e) => alert("Capture:C Target:" + e.target.id)
}

ReactDOM
  .render(<App {...props} />, 
  document.getElementById("app"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out! There was a bug. 
I am not passing any props to the Top component, so the events are not being called. I needed the following. Stupid mistake but easily done when refactoring.

```
<Top {...props}>
```